# Problem while writing a File using TwinCAT 3

Tags: plc, twincat

I am a beginner level TwinCAT user, I have to use TwinCAT to simulate a simulator and collect data for some analysis, I am facing problem while trying to record the data in CSV format using TwinCAT function blocks.(I am using ST for my case).

I already asked a question on how to write a CSV file which was answered by ziga (LOOK INI COMMENTS)[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76112520/how-do-i-save-data-from-my-plc-in-excel-or-csv-format-in-twincat), it worked fine when I ran it on local host but when I integrated the file writer on the system containing my simulator's operation code attached with PLC there was this [PROBLEM](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Xugqb6ns3llzw33WwSapZUXMOGR14m8G?usp=sharing) I have entered the correct sFileName and sFilePath but the program still shows error while opening file with error code 0X70C.

@chrisbeardy
I did some changes, I have changed the location of the file to just 'C:'. Although the eFileWriteState value remains at IDLE but STILL THE FILE IS NOT BEING WRITTEN
[this the error I am getting for some reason the state ERROR has value 3 as constant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTAoh.png)

Comment: Error 0x70C is DEVICE_NOTFOUND. Why are you not providing a sNetId?

Comment: You need to provide NetId of the target device as well as proper file path. You should read the documentation on the fbs I used in the example - note that it is just an example, you should implement error handling proper request for when to write etc...

Comment: do I need to input the I.P. address of the PLC from where data is coming or the PC where I am storing my file. If it is PLC then I am going to use 6 PLC in my system how can I input there IP addresses in sNetID ???

Comment: https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_system/30977547.html&id=

Answer (score 0):

In order to open a file in TwinCat, the entire folder structure must be present at first, it will only create the file if it does not exist, not the containing folders. Please check all the following folders exist:

Users/PC1/Desktop

I would also try writing not to the desktop in case there is a permissions issue. Try creating just a folder in the C drive e.g. C:/Test and writing there.

Comment: I put the file in the C:\ ,although there are no errors but the data is not being written. I have all the access rights and i have store the file on the local PC so there is no need to define sNetID. Please help...

Comment: You need to define the AMS Net ID of the target system. The sNetId is **not** the same as the IP address.

Comment: @manjotsanghera Error 0x70C is file not found [link](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_system/30977547.html&id=4702287923023522286) and you are correct, if writing to the local system an AMS ID is not required. I assume since you changed the file destination to the C:\ that the 0x70C error disappeared? If you say there are no more errors, but you see no data, do you see the new file with no contents, if this is the case, you must close the file in twincat using FB_FileClose to be able to view the file in notepad for example.

Comment: @chrisbeardy Please refer to the contents on the [LINK](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gjnag15e373sP7bFssbepm1qjJx5tMVh?usp=sharing) to see the problem.

Comment: @manjotsanghera , I think you are looking for the file in the wrong place, as you have set the NET ID to local, the file will be saved on the PLC itself, not your development PC.